# Symfony 2.8 Unable to find template "FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig"

Tags: symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to overload my views of FOSUserBundle. As seen on a tutorial, I copy the views in the bundle into `app/resources/FOSuserBundle`

After following the tutorial so far, I have the following error:

> Unable to find template "FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig"
>   (looked into: C:\wamp64\www\Project\app/Resources/views,
>   C:\wamp64\www\Project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form,
>   C:\wamp64\www\Project\vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu/Resources/views)

I do not understand where I was wrong, knowing that I followed the tutorial without changing anything.

If someone would have a solution to offer me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of FOSUSerBundle do this and it will work:

```
app/resources/FOSuserBundle/views/Security
```

Replaces 'FOSUserBundle' with 'Project'